# INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS suddenly empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, information-schema

Yesterday I developed an SQL query using the COLUMN_NAMES field from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS on an SQL Server database.
The query worked perfectly fine, especially the query of COLUMN_NAMES correctly output the name of my columns.

However, this morning I tried re-running the exact same query and this time I got as a result an empty table. Narrowing down the problem, it came down to the following query suddenly giving 0 rows:

```
SELECT 
    COLUMN_NAME
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME = 'MyTableName'
ORDER BY 
    ORDINAL_POSITION
```

I did strictly no changes to the Server itself. Does anyone has some insight on what could have happened ?

Comment: The documentation about [Metadata Visibility Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/metadata-visibility-configuration?view=sql-server-ver15) may help here.

Comment: Connected as another user today?

Comment: @jarlh I'm not the only one accessing the database, but myself, I always connect with the same login (windows authentication).

Comment: Are you sure that you execute your query in the context of the same database? Can you add it's name explicitly (FROM  your_db.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS)?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so as @sepupic suggested, I tried adding the database name to the query, i.e

```
SELECT 
    COLUMN_NAME
FROM 
    MyDBName.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME = 'MyTableName'
ORDER BY 
    ORDINAL_POSITION
```

and it did solve the problem. I am not sure if I understand why the query did work from the exact same context yesterday without this DB name added.

I guess in any case it's good practice to add it to the query, so I'll stick with this.

Comment: Probably yesterday you had opened a query editor when that database was highlighted, and it thus opened the connection as defaulting to that database (as if you typed `use SomeDbName;`), but today you didn't, so it didn't.